# -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to JSON objects

Tags: ios, json

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I get a very strange error with this code:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest*)setupRequestWithService:(NSString*)service andMethod:(NSString*)method
{
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.svc/%@", serverUrl, service, method];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    // Set authentication token.
    NSLog(@"???????????? %@", authenticationToken);
    if (authenticationToken == nil)
        NSLog(@"NULL AUTHTOKEN");
    if ([authenticationToken isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        NSLog(@"NSNULL AUTHTOKEN");
    if (request == nil)
        NSLog(@"NULL REQUEST");
    [request addValue:authenticationToken forHTTPHeaderField:REQUEST_HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN];

    return request;
}
```

This is my log:

```
???????????? <null>
NSNULL AUTHTOKEN
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b5a5090
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b5a5090'
```

It seems that `authenticationToken` is `NULL`. But I don't understand that, if `authenticationToken` is `NULL` why I don't see `NULL AUTHTOKEN` on the log.

I get this error the second time I run that method, the first time, I don't get any error. This is my log:

```
???????????? (null)
NULL AUTHTOKEN
```

By the way:

```
NSString* authenticationToken;
```

**Any advice?**

Maybe there is a `Memory Leak` somewhere...

Comment: it's NSNull, not nil. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You need to check with if([NSNull null]== authenticationToken){NSLog(@"NULL AUTHTOKEN");}

Comment: Yep, probably you goth authenticationToken from JSON, and it had a null for that value, so an NSNull object is what's given to you.  You can actually do `authenticationToken == [NSNull null]` to test for this, since there is only ever exactly one NSNull object in the app.

Comment: @HotLicks If you add your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

My solution to this maddening use of NSNull by JSON interpreters is to create a category on NSNull, where I define integerValue, floatValue, length, etc - return 0 for all. Everytime you get another crash add a new category. I think I had 6 or 7 when I had this issue.

The problem with NOT doing this is you have to look for the NULL everywhere in your converted objects - a PITA in my opinion.

EDIT: the code I'm using, all in a NSNull+JSON.m file:

```
@interface NSNull (JSON)
@end

@implementation NSNull (JSON)

- (NSUInteger)length { return 0; }

- (NSInteger)integerValue { return 0; };

- (float)floatValue { return 0; };

- (NSString *)description { return @"0(NSNull)"; }

- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator { return @[]; }

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key { return nil; }

- (BOOL)boolValue { return NO; }

@end
```

EDIT2: Now in Swift 3:

```
extension NSNull {
   func length() -> Int { return 0 }

   func integerValue() -> Int { return 0 }

   func floatValue() -> Float { return 0 };

   open override var description: String { return "0(NSNull)" }

   func componentsSeparatedByString(separator: String) -> [AnyObject] { return [AnyObject]() }

   func objectForKey(key: AnyObject) -> AnyObject? { return nil }

   func boolValue() -> Bool { return false }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message is pretty clear. `NSNull` and `nil` are different things:

```
The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in 
collection objects (which don’t allow nil values).
```

If you want to check if `authenticationToken` is `NSNull` try: `[authenticationToken isEqual: [NSNull null]]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't help. I only want to know what's happening! I have a `NSString` and then it changes to `NSNull`.

Comment: @VansFannel Then you should ask that question.

Answer (score 2):

In line with David H's answer, how about a category on `NSNull` that just uses ObjC's message forwarding to "do nothing", to emulate the runtime's behavior when sending messages to `nil`?

Like this:

```
@interface NSNull (ForwardInvocation)

@end

@implementation NSNull (ForwardInvocation)

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return [NSNull methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(description)];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    // do nothing; prevent 'unrecognized selector' crashes
}

@end
```

The `[NSNull methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(description)];` takes advantage of the fact that `NSNull` inherits from `NSObject`, which provides the `description` method. This satisfies the forwarding mechanism requirement for implementing `-methodSignatureForSelector:`.

Comment: I believe this won't work. What my solution does is return a typed "nothing", so that the receiver can use the value in the same way it would a "real" answer. Note in one case an empty array is returned. Also you get the unique description so you can see the nulls while debugging.

Comment: It does works in my case, and it feels like a more generic solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidH You're correct, my solution was more geared toward ignoring objc messages sent to NSNull, to avoid the unknown selector error. But for providing default values for JSON parsing, your solution is better-suited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes because your method return an NSNull object.
You can't check `[authenticationToken isEqual:[NSNull null]])` because `[NSNull null]` give an instance of an object. So it's different from your object itself.
If you want to check if you received an NSNull object you need to check like this: `[authenticationToken isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]` instead.