# iOS & Stackmob - [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, stackmob

In my iOS app I'm trying to update user information in the database (with Stackmob), but I keep getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance."

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIButton *)sender {

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];
NSPredicate *predicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@", self.username];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicte];

[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest onSuccess:^(NSArray *results) {

    NSManagedObject *todoObject = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    [todoObject setValue:@"example@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];

    [self.managedObjectContext saveOnSuccess:^{
        NSLog(@"You updated the todo object!");
    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error! %@", error);
    }];

} onFailure:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error fetching: %@", error);

}];
}
```

Here's the full error I'm getting:

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ec5678

2013-07-21 12:01:25.773 [29207:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ec5678'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some where you getting Nil value or object and you try to set nil that why you got this error. check befor setValue with it's nil or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [-\[NSNull length\]: unrecognized selector sent to... A memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607960/nsnull-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-a-memory-leak)

Comment: Could you print self.username and see what it contains?

Answer (score 42):

I think it may because your self.username is empty. Note that if you are getting the username data from json , you can't use 
`if(username){...}` but

```
if(![username isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

to avoid empty data because the json interpreter will generate an `NSNull` object.

Comment: Although this solution works but I have found a better solution here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607960/nsnull-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-a-memory-leak/16610117

Comment: @पवन While that may work in certain circumstances, it's a pretty dangerous strategy to use in production.

Comment: but what does JSON have to do with this?