# Xcode, unrecognized selector sent to instance - but on what line?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm getting the common error when dealing with JSON,

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102aa8b50
```

I completely understand this, know how to deal with it and so on (BTW here's a clever approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/16610117/294884 )

My problem is, in Xcode, how do I tell which [  length] call caused the problem??

Xcode seems to simply show it happening at "line 7 of main" - !

I'm not an expert on debugging in Xcode, what to do?

[image]

Just BTW on the specific example problem (NSNull issue), I draw your attention to the amazing library JR mentions below: github.com/jrturton/NSJSONSerialization-NSNullRemoval

Comment: Post the rest of that crash log here. (you can just copy and paste)

Comment: Post the whole crash log please.

Comment: Possibly of use to you: https://github.com/jrturton/NSJSONSerialization-NSNullRemoval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an "Exception Breakpoint" in the breakpoint pane of Xcode.

[image: Add Exception Breakpoint]

After you have added this all exceptions raised by code will be highlighted on the correct line, most of the time.

You are getting `NSNull` object because the JSON is containing something like:

```
{
    "someKey": null
}
```

Then when you get the value using `[json objectForKey:@"someKey"]` it will return a `NSNull` object and not `nil`. Since `nil` would mean that the kay was not present, which is its.

You can easily fix that with a simple Objective-C category:

**NSDictionary+NotNull.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/*! This category extends NSDictionary to work around an issue with NSNull object.
 */
@interface NSDictionary (NotNull)

/*! @abstract Returns the value associated with a given key, but only if the value is not NSNull.
    @param aKey The key for which to return the corresponding value.
    @return The value associated with the given key, or nil if no value is associated with the key, or the value is NSNull.
 */
- (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey;
```

**NSDictionary+NotNull.m**

```
#import "NSDictionary+NotNull.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (NotNull)

- (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey
{
    id object = [self objectForKey:aKey];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return object;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi RC ... "will be highlighted on the correct line, **most of the time**" -- it DOES NOT WORK for me!  Arrrk!  PS as I mentioned, I completely understand how to solve the problem at hand; I just want to know how the hell to get Xcode to show me where it happens?!!  Thanks!

Comment: Shit -- it just worked!  :)  Clearly Xcode is scared of you :)  I guess it "sometimes doesn't work" is that correct?  Thanks!

Comment: Well that is why I stated "most of the time", because sometimes it is not catching the correct line or highlighting the wrong one.

Comment: Gotchya - I guess that's the key.  Just TBC, why does that happen - is there anything to understand about that?

Comment: Well when you pass the object retrieved from the JSON to some other class or method somewhere deep in the Objective-C framework it is calling the `length` method, because it was thinking the object passed was a `NSString`.

Comment: Gotchya - and in that case, Xcode struggles to know the "originating" line of code in your consumer code base, right?  Thanks!

Comment: BTW. on the specific problem mentioned.  I've never found a really good solution when using "modern" syntax, e.g., cell.authorName.text = CLOUD.searchResults[thisRow][@"author"]; ....

Comment: I suppose, your own NSSafeDictionary, overriding objectForKey, would be the best solution, really.

Comment: Well yes you could override the `objectForKey:` but it is not really a road I would go.